# How to type fraction symbols on iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios, keyboard

Many character sets provide single special characters for fractions like 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, etc. Can these be typed on an iPad?

I have found [GlyphBoard](http://mrgan.com/gb/) that lets you paste them in but it dates back to 2009 and I wondered if native support may have been added in the interim.

Comment: I have often wished for an IOS equivalent of "Unicode Hex Input"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The built-in iOS keyboard does not support this, but you can add a shortcut from **Settings > General > Keyboard**. This way you only have to copy/paste once.

[image] [image]

Comment: A good trick, but he probably has to prepare 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5.... and maybe some 2/3, 2/5

Comment: True, but only once! And here are some more, for reference: ¼½¾⅓⅔⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅛⅜⅝⅞

Comment: I feel his pain

Comment: That's a clever way to do it if you use fractions often. Thankfully I don't and was wondering more out of curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

There are apps which mimic the Mac Character viewer, which I use for once-in-a-while symbols that aren't on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

i put these all into one keyboard shortcut.  It's Easier to backout what's not needed than to make many small shortcuts or do it manually each time.  Not a perfect solutions but …